# Python2.7 - Is writing to an imported variable atomic?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, global-variables, atomic

My project has the following structure:

A coordinator script that imports 2 modules and makes a thread for the main function of each.

I have a variable I need to share between the two imported modules. Module 1 writes it, and Module 2 reads it (asynchronically). Since read and write are atomic, it should be thread safe. In Python though, global variables are module scoped, therefore, a global variable approach does not work.

My intention is to add this shared variable to my config module and have both modules import it (it's probably super dirty, but my Python knowledge is limited). I think this would at least let me work around scoping, but I don't know if atomicity is maintained if the shared variable is imported.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking if modifications are _atomic_ (guaranteed to happen all at once), or just if they are _visible_ to both modules?

Comment: You can use `Lock` with `Thread` to form `mutex` and you can be sure your reads/writes are consistent.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for your reply. Both, actually. I don't want to read imported.X with Module 2 if Module 1 is writing to it, atomicity would easily take care of that. I understand that by placing X on a third module and importing it from both, it would be visible to both, and I know write operations are atomic within scope, I just don't know if write is still atomic is if the variable is imported.

Comment: @ikac `Lock` would add a layer of synchronization that won't work for what I'm doing Both threads "run free". I need to rely on the atomicity of operations for I/O performance. I just need to confirm if write atomicity is maintained for an imported variable. Thanks!